# Mandrill link to open a mobile app

Tags: templates, mailchimp, mandrill

I am using Mandrill email template. I need an email with a link to open my custom app. What I put in the template is

```
Please click this&nbsp;<a mc:disable-tracking="" href="*|RESET_URL|*" target="_blank" title="LINK">LINK</a>
```

The RESET_URL variable I passed in is `spectrum://reset?token=ABC`, spectrum is my mobile app. But when the email sent out, the link become `<a title="LINK">LINK</a>`. Look like the href was removed. How should I do it?

Comment: It can be mailchimp doesn't recognize the protocol and adding/changing it. I dont think they support `tel` as a protocol as well which a lot of people are now using. Maybe you can create a support ticket for them to have a look at it for a walkaround.

Comment: any alternative solutions for this?

Comment: It would be best to ask their support team. They might give you the best answer or a walkaround.